# Prevent date formatting in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code where a workbook should be saved as file path + prefix + whatever date the user entered into user unput box. The date enter should be in the format of MMDDYYYY. The problem is VBA converts the date and saves it as MM-DD-YYYY format. How do I prevent this.

My code:

```
With prevdaily
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ' Check for year folder and create if needed
            If Len(Dir("G:\AccPac ERP Daily Reports\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir "G:\AccPac ERP Daily Reports\" & Year(Date)
            End If

            ' Check for month folder and create if needed
            If Len(Dir("G:\AccPac ERP Daily Reports\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm ") & MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir "G:\AccPac ERP Daily Reports\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm ") & MonthName(Month(Date), False)
            End If
                fname2 = InputBox("Please enter date of Daily Income Journal to save")
                fname2 = fname2 & ".xlsx"
                fpath = "G:\AccPac ERP Daily Reports\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm ") & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fpath & "Daily Income Journal-" & fname
```

Thank you Barranka!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `format()` function to create a string with the desired format:

Example:

```
Dim strDate as String
strDate = format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
```

Read:

- [MSDN: `Format` funnction (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx)